# Boolean Indexing n-D Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I could not apply bool values into given data:

```
import numpy as np

bool_values = np.array([False, False, True, False, True])
data = np.array([[11.0, 22.0, 0.0, 44.0, 55.0],
                 [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0]])

expected_answer = [[0,55], [30,50]]
```

I tried it as:

```
expected_answer = data[bool_values]
```

Comment: You mean `[0.0, 55]` right?

Comment: Aha yes, now corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to do this:

```
In [28]:
bool_values = np.array([False, False, True, False, True])
data = np.array([[11.0, 22.0, 0.0, 44.0, 55.0],
 [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0]])
data[:,bool_values]

Out[28]:
array([[  0.,  55.],
       [ 30.,  50.]])
```

The above applies the mask to every row